# REST API Azure Data Share Autorization Header

Tags: azure, api, azure-synapse

I'm trying to trigger an Azure Data Share with a web activity in an Synapse Integrate pipeline.
After doing the post I received the error that the autorization header is missing.
Where can I find or create that (I assume) token?

[image]

Hope you can provide me a solution! Kind regards
D

Answer (score 0):

1. You can retrieve the token using web activity with [POST method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/561367/adf-rest-api-bearer-token.html) to your API or you can retrieve from [Azure AD](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013)
2. Once you get the token pass it in you web activity under Headers as authorization. You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/388418/error-code-2108-error-calling-the-endpoint-in-web.html) to pass the authorization token under header